# MySQL Connector/.NET not appearing

Tags: ssis, mysql-connector

I installed the Connector/NET version 8.0.33 from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/ on my system. When using Visual Studio 2022, 64-bit, version 17.6.2 with SQL Server Integration Services 16.0.5209.0, I'm not able to connect.

When I create a new ADO.NET connection manager, the MySql provider isn't showing up.

Is there a versioning issue with running the latest SSIS tools?